# Expresión regular para coincidir con texto entre comillas simples

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

Necesito extraer algunos datos desde una respuesta recibida por jmeter, para luego llenar el formulario y enviarlo. La expresión que me funciona (a medias) es:

```
asignarValores\(\'agregarDeudaCarroCompra\'\,(.+)\, (.+)\, (.+)\, (.+)\, (.+)\, (.+)\)
```

que busca la línea

```
asignarValores('agregarDeudaCarroCompra', '12345678', '01', 'INS', '2009', '2', '0')
```

y después captura los valores por su posición `$1`, `$2`, `$3`...
El problema es que la expresion regular me toma los valores con comilla simple

- Match[1][1]='12345678'
- Match[1][2]='01'
- Match[1][3]='INS'
- Match[1][4]='2009'
- Match[1][5]='2'
- Match[1][6]='0'

He intentado varias formas de sacarlo desde la misma expresión regular, pero no lo logro, agradezco cualquier comentario al respecto.

Para probar la expresiones utilizo el sitio https://regex101.com/r/ZOLlyd/1

Comment: Puede haber comillas simples escapadas dentro de las comillas?? Puede haber parámetros que no estén entre comillas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Antes que nada, hay que tener mucho cuidado con expresiones como la
>   que estás intentando, donde una coincidencia de `.+` puede coincidir
>   con lo mismo que la siguiente con`.+`, ya que son el típico ejemplo de
>   una expresión regular que genera un backtracking catastrófico. Es
>   decir, **nunca utilices esa expresión**. Más información en 
>   [*Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

---

Se puede resolver de 3 formas, dependiendo el grado de complejidad. De más simple a más compleja:

**1. Texto entre comillas simples**

Ahora bien, para que las comillas no entren dentro de la captura de un grupo, se deben poner por fuera. Y, dentro del grupo, podemos buscar que coincida con cualquier caracter que no sea una comilla: `[^']*`.

Expresión regular:

```
asignarValores\('([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)'\)
```

[Demo en regexplanet.com](http://fiddle.re/yyyyy8g4t4d) (hacer click en Java).
<sub>Si realmente preferís en regex101, [esta es la demo](https://regex101.com/r/Stu3FZ/1), pero hay que tener en cuenta que regex101 no usa el mismo motor de regex que Java.</sub>

Esta es la forma más simple y más eficiente de coincidir con texto entre comillas (-si bien sirve para otros casos, realmente, que ni se te ocurra usar `.*?` acá).

**2. Comillas escapadas dentro de las comillas**

Si se permiten comillas simples escapadas como `\'` dentro de un parámetro, entonces tenemos que coincidir con todos los caracteres que no sean `\` ni `'`, y luego permitir coincidir con una barra seguida de cualquier caracter (`\.`). Es decir, que para cada parámetro usaríamos:

```
'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'
```

- Si bien hay patrones más acotados para esto mismo, esta es la forma más eficiente de realizarlo, empleando una técnica llamada [*unrolling the loop*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

Regex repitiendo esta estructura para los 7 parámetros:

```
asignarValores\('([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)', '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)', '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)', '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)', '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)', '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)', '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'\)
```

[Demo en regexplanet.com](http://fiddle.re/yyyyy4fnz6r)  (hacer click en Java).
O en [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Stu3FZ/2).

**3. Comillas simples o comillas dobles**

Si se quiere permitir tanto `'` como `"` para cada parámetro, entonces lo modificamos un poco para que coincida con las 2 opciones:

```
(['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\1
```

- `(['"])` ::: Guardamos la referencia al tipo de comillas que se abrió en `$1`.
- `([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)` ::: Captura el contenido en `$2`:

  - `[^'"\\]*` ::: caracteres que no son `'`, `"`, ni `\`
  - `(?:(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"])[^'"\\]*)*` ::: Una de las excepciones, seguidas de más texto que no son comillas ni barras, todo esto todas las veces que pueda ocurrir (repetido con `*`).
    Las excepciones `(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"])` son:

    1. `\\.` ::: una barra seguida de cualquier caracter, o
    2. `(?!\1)['"]` ::: si no está seguido por la comilla con la que se abrió, una comilla (es decir, si el texto está entre comillas dobles, que pueda coincidir con comillas simples, y viceversa).
- `\1` ::: Coincide con el mismo tipo de comillas conque se abrió.

El regex completo nos queda:

```
asignarValores\((['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\1, (['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\3)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\3, (['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\5)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\5, (['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\7)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\7, (['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\9)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\9, (['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\11)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\11, (['"])([^'"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|(?!\13)['"])[^'"\\]*)*)\13\)
```

Donde sólo nos interesan las capturas creadas por los grupos pares (los grupos 1, 3, 5, ... los usamos para capturar el tipo de comillas).

[Demo en regexplanet.com](http://fiddle.re/yyyyyuj0b0d)  (hacer click en Java).
O en [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Stu3FZ/3).

Comment: Muchas gracias!, buenisima respuesta. De verdad practicamente me hiciste los que debia hacer yo...